# Why with while .join() gives me error and without it works

Tags: javascript

So, I have this code, I'm just trying to do a reverse thing with js. I introduce a number and it sorts itself from max to lower and lower to max, with two variables max and min. I substract the max to the min, and it repeats until the result is 6174.

I don't know why when I put all this in a while max.join() gives me an error: "Uncaught TypeError: max.join is not a function at <'anonymous>:28:17"

But without the while it works.

```js
 var num = prompt('Introduzca un número de 4 digitos de al menos 2 digitos distintos', '1234');

 var output = [],
  sNum = num.toString(),
  n = 0,
  max = [],
     min = [],
     a = 0,
     kap= 6174,
     v = 1;
  
   while (a != kap) {
      for (var i = 0, len = sNum.length; i < len; i++) {
        output.push(+sNum.charAt(i));
      }

      min = output.sort((a, b) => a - b );

      var x=3;

      for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        max[c] = min[x];
        x--;
      }

      min = min.join('');
      max = max.join('');
      sNum = parseInt(max)-parseInt(min);
      
      if (sNum == kap) {
       a = kap;
      }
      else {
       a = 0;
        v++;
      }
   }
   
   console.log(v);
   console.log(a);
```

```js
 var num = prompt('Introduzca un número de 4 digitos de al menos 2 digitos distintos', '1234');

 var output = [],
  sNum = num.toString(),
  n = 0,
  max = [],
     min = [],
     a = 0,
     kap= 6174,
     v = 1;
  
      for (var i = 0, len = sNum.length; i < len; i++) {
        output.push(+sNum.charAt(i));
      }

      min = output.sort((a, b) => a - b );

      var x=3;

      for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        max[c] = min[x];
        x--;
      }

      min = min.join('');
      max = max.join('');
      sNum = parseInt(max)-parseInt(min);
   
   console.log(max);
   console.log(min);
   console.log(sNum);
```

Thank you so much, I finally saw the problem and now I have the code complete :)

```js
 var num = prompt('Introduzca un número de 4 digitos de al menos 2 digitos distintos', '1234');

 var sNum = num.toString(),
  n = 0, 
  a = 0,
  kap= 6174,
  v = 1;

 if (num == (1111 || 2222 || 3333 || 4444 || 5555 || 6666 || 7777 || 8888 || 9999 || 0000 || 0)) {
  console.log(8);
 }

 else if (num == 6174) {
  console.log(0);
 }

 else if (sNum.length < 4) {
  while (sNum.length < 4) {
   sNum = ('0' + sNum);
  }
  if (sNum == "0000") {
   console.log(8);
  }
  else {
   calculoKaprekar();
  }
 }

 else {
  calculoKaprekar();
 }

   function calculoKaprekar () {
    while (a != kap) {
     var output = [];

     sNum = sNum.toString();

   for (var i = 0, len = sNum.length; i < len; i++) {
    output.push(+sNum.charAt(i));
   }
  
   var max = [],
    min = [];

   min = output.sort((a, b) => a - b );

   var x=3;

   for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
    max[c] = min[x];
    x--;
   }

   min = min.join('');
   max = max.join('');
   sNum = parseInt(max)-parseInt(min);

   if (sNum == kap) {
    a = kap;
   }
   else {
    v++;
   }
    }
    console.log(v);
 }
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a string hence `min` and `max` will be strings after the first round of your loop. And strings don't have a `.join()` method

Comment: I guess simply moving `min & max` variable to inside `while` loop will solve your problem.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal No it won't: _"The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global."_

Comment: Well I tried it online and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first iteration `max` is an array as you expect:

```
[
  4,
  3,
  2,
  1
]
```

However, within that first iteration the value is being reassigned:

```
max = max.join('');
```

So on the second iteration, it is now `"4321"` *(a string)*.

And `"4321".join("")` is not a function since [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is not a function on strings.

Comment: _"So on the second iteration, it is now `4321`"_ - This should have at least quotes around the value or even better say that `4321` in this case is a _string_ and not an array anymore.